# TEC Design and Qc generated?

Tags: mosfet-driver, pid-controller, heatsink, peltier

i've been working on a project in order to cool a thermal box by using peltier elements PID controlled..

I've tried different designs on how to obtain maximum efficiency according to my rig, however it seems like my cells are not driving QC enough.

Here's the TEC datasheet.

[image]

i'm using 2 in parallel. i measured its current and voltage, respectively 5amp and 5v. therefore, 2.5amp per cell. exacly like this i was able to reach 8ºC on Tamb of 17 degrees. Assuming my heatsink at 20 degrees, my DT is 20-8 = 12ºC right?

driving 2.5 amps at datasheet QC may be pathetic, once this data dosent even appear on this chart.

in conclusion, would i be able to increase its current in order to achive higher QCs? I'm sure my heatsink will perform the work, even though the question remain on how to calculate heatsink Qc...

Question:
Would be better using a single peltier? 
Should i drive more current?

Still, i'm trying to upgrade its design by:
1- replacing black screws to an isolated one
2- use a higher density styrofoam
3- Increase the separation between heatsink using a thin aluminum plate over peltier cells

Here's the project[image]

[image]

Here's the circuit . A voltage follower, driving the OPAMP controller input(INQ) direct to the load. I may be limited at 5amps(i tested) , once my VG is 12-2(to turn on OPAMP) and VS is 5v from the miccontroller
[image: Circuit]

Comment: 5 volts/1.08 ohms = 4.6 amps. You cannot put 10A through the tec without increasing the voltage.

Comment: Why are you using your MOSFET as a current limiting resistor? Are you trying to make a soldering iron? Because that's what you got in that configuration. - Analogy of what you are doing: Instead of chopping wood effortless with your axe, you instead push your axe as hard as you can against the wood and hope that it splits. This is so inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thermal loss in your system will be through the TEC.  To get the most of your TEC you need to drive it hard.  More power!  Or take one of the TEC's out of the system and see how cold it gets with just one.